# URL routing with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, bitnami

I am currently learning PHP and I have been attempting to make a PHP MVC website. However I am unable to get the URL routing to work correctly in my config file.

Here is my bitnami httpd-vhosts.conf file (as I am developing this on a bitnami server):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName dev.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/dev/htdocs"
  SSLEngine on
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$ [NC]
  RewriteRule . /index.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/dev/conf/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/dev/conf/server.key"
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/dev/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

Based on my understanding this is what I am expecting this to do. Direct this URL:

```
https://dev.example.com/contact
```

to:

```
https://dev.example.com/index.php?url=contact
```

However it always takes my to this URL

```
https://dev.example.com/index.php?url=/contact
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been struggling with this issue for a few hours.

Comment: Use this instead `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`.

Comment: Hi @Karkouch . Thanks for the help but I am still having the same issue after trying your code.

Comment: Hi, Bitnami Engineer here. If you want to remove the / of the URL, you only need to make a small change in the @Karkouch solution. Use this configuration line `RewriteRule "^/?(.*)" /index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: @JotaMartos That got it working for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perfect! I'll add that as a new answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here.

If you want to remove the / of the URL, you only need to make a small change in the @Karkouch solution. Use this configuration line

```
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)" /index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

And restart Apache after that :)